# JavaScript line doesn't work in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Why does this line as the first line of a TypeScript program give an error?

```
var curry = require('lodash').curry;
```

The error is: 'Cannot find name 'require' at ...

Can you deconstruct my line of code to explain specifically what that error message is trying to tell me? Not how to fix it, but what misinterpretation of what I read leads to that error message?

Also, as this same line works correctly in JavaScript, doesn't this violate the "all js is also legal ts" rule?

Finally, what is the 'right' TypeScript to create a variable 'curry' that is bound to the curry method of the loads library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you deconstruct my line of code to explain specifically what that error message is trying to tell me?

TypeScript is seeing you use a variable that it doesn't know about. TypeScript doesn't assume that any arbitrary variable exists (otherwise it would never be able to warn you about using a variable called `reqiure`).

> Also, as this same line works correctly in javascript, doesn't this violate the "all js is also legal ts" rule?

It's legal TypeScript. The compiler is still emitting JS. It's just warning you about a thing that looks incorrect.

> Finally, what is the 'right' typescript to create a variable 'curry' that is bound to the curry method of the loads library?

I would include `lodash.d.ts` and write this:

```
import lodash = require('lodash');
var curry = lodash.curry;
```

Comment: Thanks! How then does the require line work in pure javascript? I guess it has to do with the node environment that is provided to the js engine?

Comment: node.js defines `require`. You should include `node.d.ts` if you want to use it directly.